# MySQL Cluster issue of ndb_mgmdon Centos7

Tags: mysql

Getting this error while entering the below command.

```
[root@localhost mysql-cluster]# ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
**-bash: ndb_mgmd: command not found**
```

Comment: config.ini

As I am using 2 nodes excluding Management Node, my **config.ini** is:
[ndb_mgmd default]
# Directory for MGM node log files
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/
[ndb_mgmd]
#Management Node db1
HostName=192.168.0.32
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=1      # Number of replicas
DataMemory=256M     # Memory allocate for data storage
IndexMemory=128M    # Memory allocate for index storage
#Directory for Data Node
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster`enter code here`

[ndbd]
#Data Node db2
HostName=192.168.0.28


[mysqld]
#SQL Node db3
HostName=192.168.0.27

Comment: Can you post your details properly formatted in the question, please?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to use the command of **ndb_mgmd**. Using MySQL 5.6.35 on Centos 7 64-bit
[root@localhost mysql-cluster]# ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
**-bash: ndb_mgmd: command not found**

This is my config.ini
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHKLO.png)

Comment: you have to write an answer to the above question here. if you want to ask something. write your own QUESTION  .

Comment: Oh my bad... but can you please answer my query.

Comment: @jojonas

Sir you can consult the attached Image of my config.ini
After doing  all the steps when use the command of ndb_mgmd then got an error of command not found. How this command can be run so that further I can proceed!!